# Выпадающий список из имеющихся значений в БД на странице для ввода нового пользователя

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

У меня возникла проблема: пишу представление для регистрации пользователя, в качестве графы "Пол" хочу вывести список значений, которые уже есть в БД в таблице Genders (Они по умолчанию создаются). Выводится ошибка, что я Бд хочу удалить, никак не получается ее обойти. Из-за чего это может быть? Подскажите пожалуйста. Скрин ошибки во вложении[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S.: Сейчас в представлении еще не все поля для ввода реализованы.

Модель для таблиц StaffVolunteers и Genders:

```
public class StaffVolunteer
    {
        public int StaffVolunteerID { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Patronymic { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public int GenderID { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public int SuperUser { get; set; }
        public bool BeReady { get; set; }
 
        public virtual Gender Gender { get; set; }
 
        public StaffVolunteer()
        {
            this.Groups = new List<Group>();
        }
        public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
 
    }
 public class Gender
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NameOfGender { get; set; }
 
        public virtual ICollection<MissingPerson> MissingPeople { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FoundStranger> FoundStrangers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<StaffVolunteer> StaffVolunteers { get; set; }
 
 
        public Gender()
        {
            this.FoundStrangers = new List<FoundStranger>();
            this.MissingPeople = new List<MissingPerson>();
            this.StaffVolunteers = new List<StaffVolunteer>();
        }
 
    }
```

Контроллер

```
public class VolunteersController : Controller
    {
        private EventContext db = new EventContext();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Reg()
        {
            SelectList genders = new SelectList(db.Genders, "Id", "NameOfGender");
            ViewBag.Genders = genders;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Reg(StaffVolunteer volun)
        {
            db.StaffVolunteers.Add(volun);
            db.SaveChanges();
 
            return RedirectToAction("Auth");
        }
....
}
```

Представление

```
@model Practice2021_2.Models.StaffVolunteer
 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<h2>Регистрация нового волонтера</h2>
 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, "Фамилия")
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, "Имя")
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Patronymic, "Отчетво")
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Patronymic)
    <br />
    <br />
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GenderID, "Пол")
    <br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GenderID, ViewBag.Genders as SelectList)
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
}
 
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

```
 public class EventContext:DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<FoundStranger> FoundStrangers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Gender> Genders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<MissingPerson> MissingPeople { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SearchCampaign> SearchCampaigns { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Set> Sets { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<StaffVolunteer> StaffVolunteers { get; set; }
        
    }
```

Вот так заполняется Таблица Genders, она с автоматической индексацией.

```
public class DbEventInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EventContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(EventContext context)
        {
            Gender g1 = new Gender { NameOfGender = "Мужской" };
            Gender g2 = new Gender { NameOfGender = "Женский" };
            context.Genders.Add(g1);
            context.Genders.Add(g2);
           ......
            context.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

Я вырезала инициализатор, который у меня был, теперь на этом же месте выходит новая ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вероятно где-то в коде у вас вызывается `Database.EnsureDeleted()`. Покажите класс контекста `EventContext` - возмножно, это в нём. Или где-то на старте приложения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov добавила код в текст вопроса

Comment: `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` - удаляет БД и создаёт заново. Где-то в вашем коде у контекста вызывается метод `Database.SetInitializer`, которому назначается `DbEventInitializer`.

Comment: @Alexander Я сейчас поставила точку останова в инициализатор и на ту строчку, где он вызывается - вообще ни разу не остановился в инициализаторе, только остановился в файле Global.asx.cs на строчке `Database.SetInitializer(new DbEventInitializer());` при запуске, но в сам инициализатор не зашел, хотя должен был, как мне кажется. Сейчас попробую его убрать.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вырезала класс инициализатора, теперь новая ошибка выходит (прикрепила скрин выше). Как вы считаете, из-за чего это может быть?